# Drawing.Line on bitmap with Image LockBits

Tags: .net, aforge

I have 20 frame per sec. and I draw some line on each frame, I am getting lines without problem but background Image stucks often. Randomly I get 10 frame same Image but lines look fine.

```
if (cizik == null)
{
BitmapData imageData = CloneOrj2.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, CloneOrj2.Width, CloneOrj2.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
UnmanagedImage tmp = new UnmanagedImage(imageData);
cizik = UnmanagedImage.Create(CloneOrj2.Width, CloneOrj2.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
tmp.Copy(cizik);
Drawing.Line(cizik, new IntPoint(XX, XX), new IntPoint(XX, XX), System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
}
else
{ 
BitmapData imageData = CloneOrj2.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, CloneOrj2.Width, CloneOrj2.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
UnmanagedImage tmp = new UnmanagedImage(imageData);
Drawing.Line(tmp, new IntPoint(XX, XX), new IntPoint(XX, XX), System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
cizik = UnmanagedImage.Create(CloneOrj2.Width, CloneOrj2.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
tmp.Copy(cizik);
}

DrawScreenActual.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)cizik.ToManagedImage().Clone();
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code is not showed completely, BUT after an LockBits you must EVER unlock the bits.

To do this, you must use the UnlockBits method in the bitmap object. I would call it after the DrawLine.

Maybe there is the problem!